# Change status of state variable in Child Component of react.js

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component like below. I have a button here named `View`.

```
class DataTable extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          modalOpen: false,
        };

        this.view = this.view.bind(this);
    }
    view() {
        this.setState({ modalOpen: true });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button className="mini ui button" onClick={this.view}>
                    <i className="user icon"></i>
                    View
                </button>
                <ModalBody modelStatus = {this.state.modalOpen}/>
            </div>
        ) 
    }
}
```

I have a child component like below

```
class ModalBody extends Component {
    state = { modalchildOpen: false }
    componentDidMount() {
        if(this.props.modelStatus) {
            this.setState({ modalchildOpen: true })
            console.log('yes')
        }
        else {
            this.setState({ modalchildOpen: false })
            console.log('no')
        }
    } 
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Modal open={this.state.modalchildOpen}/>
            </div>
        ) 
    }   
}
```

I would like to change status of `modalchildOpen`from `false` to `true` while clicking on Button `View`. In another action I would like to change status of `modalchildOpen`from `true` to `false` in the child component.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @lustoykov about how you would normally set the modal open/closed value through state. However, if you want to update the state based on props passed down from the parent, what you’re probably looking for is the componentWillReceiveProps life cycle method. This method runs anytime your child component receives props and you can compare the old props to the new props. You can then set the state inside that function.

Reference this link: 
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops

Please note, there is newer version of this life cycle method called getDerivedStateFromProps. Be sure to check your versioning and see if you can use the new method as the old one will eventually become deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue using below code.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){  
      this.setState({
        modalchildOpen: nextProps.modelStatus,
    })
}
```

Thanks all.